# OFL license and errors

Tags: license, ofl

If someone accidentally (or otherwise) violates the [OFL](https://openfontlicense.org/) license, it's clear that their licence is terminated.  But if they fix the violation, can they get a renewed licence, or have they lost it for ever?

Comment: The license is very clear that it is terminated; however I suspect the question you really want to ask is if it is possible to get a new license grant after the license has been terminated.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I am referring to the SIL OFL 1.1, which says that, if any of the conditions are not followed, the license then becomes null and void. Considering my example, does that imply that, if the error is fixed, the license becomes valid again?

Comment: @askingQuestions I hope my edit is in the spirit of your underlying question, as expressed in your comment above.  Please revert it, and accept my apologies, if it's not.

Answer (score 4):

In the absence of any better answer, I'll note that the OFL has a termination clause, but no reinstatement clause.  That differs from eg [GPLv3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html), which discusses reinstatement in s8.  So I don't think we can read a clause into the OFL which is patently not there.

However, I also note that licences don't inhere in content; instead, their obligations attach to recipients through the act of conveyance.  So while I don't see there's any right to reinstate your lost licence, I think you can just get a fresh one by getting a fresh copy of the font from wherever you got it the first time.